# Numpy.around() converts an ndarray len 45 into an ndarray len 1

Tags: python, numpy

I have this ndarray

```
>>> y_pred_test=[1.         3.         1.986      1.         1.79266667 1.048
 1.         3.         2.         2.         3.         3.
 1.         1.976      3.         2.         1.         1.
 2.03       1.         1.976      1.16966667 1.06       2.
 2.         2.         2.         2.         2.02       3.
 1.         1.         2.02       1.02       1.         1.12511111
 3.         2.07       2.         3.         1.24177778 1.
 2.         2.         2.        ]

>>> type(y_pred_test)

numpy.ndarray

>>> len(y_pred_test)

45
```

and need to round it, so I use np.around

```
>>> np.around([y_pred_test], decimals=0, out=y_pred_test_round[:,])

>>> print(y_pred_test_round)`

[[1. 3. 2. 1. 2. 1. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3. 3. 1. 2. 3. 2. 1. 1. 2. 1. 2. 1. 1. 2.
  2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2.]]
```

But the problem is that now I have an ndarray with len 1

```
>>> type(y_pred_test_round)

numpy.ndarray

>>> len(y_pred_test_round)

1
```

I also tried

```
for i in range(len(y_pred_test)):
    np.around([y_pred_test], decimals=0, out=y_pred_test_round[:,i])
```

and get this error

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (45,) doesn't match the broadcast shape (1,45)
```

I can't find the way to fix it, anyone can help please?

Comment: would calling `y_pred_test_round[0]` fix your problem?

Comment: It would be easier for someone to help you if you provided a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For example, you haven't shown how you created `y_pred_test_round`.

Answer (score 2):

Change

`np.around([y_pred_test], decimals=0, out=y_pred_test_round[:,])`

to

`np.around(y_pred_test, decimals=0, out=y_pred_test_round[:,])`

You don't need to put `y_pred_test` into `[]` in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, finally I solved this way

`y_pred_test_round = np.around(y_pred_test, decimals=0)`
`print(y_pred_test_round)`

[1. 3. 2. 1. 2. 1. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3. 3. 1. 2. 3. 2. 1. 1. 2. 1. 2. 1. 1. 2.
 2. 2. 2. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 2. 1. 1. 1. 3. 2. 2. 3. 1. 1. 2. 2. 2.]

`len(y_pred_test_round)`

45